# What types of integrals cannot be solved using improper Riemann-Stieltjes Integration?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I came across the wikipedia discussion of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral. The first sentence in the "Generalization" section gave me pause:

*An important generalization is the Lebesgue–Stieltjes integral which generalizes the Riemann–Stieltjes integral in a way analogous to how the Lebesgue integral generalizes the Riemann integral. If improper Riemann–Stieltjes integrals are allowed, the **Lebesgue integral is not strictly more general than the Riemann–Stieltjes integral.***

I always thought that whatever can be solved by RS integrals can also be solved via LS integrals, but this sentence suggests that neither is strictly dominant over the other wrt what can be solved.

In addition, the sentence after that seems to say that RS integrals can handle integration over Banach spaces:

"*The Riemann–Stieltjes integral also generalizes to the case when either the integrand ƒ or the integrator g take values in a Banach space. If g : [a,b] → X takes values in the Banach space X, then it is natural to assume that it is of strongly bounded variation, meaning that*

$\sup \sum_i \|g(t_i)-g(t_{i+1})\|_X < \infty$

*the supremum being taken over all finite partitions*

$a=t_0\le t_1\le\cdots\le t_n=b$ *of the interval $[a,b]$*

It seems like RS integrals are more powerful than I previously thought. Are there genuine cases where even an improper RS integral cannot produce an answer?

Comment: Interesting to study the improper case. However, in Banach space,  we don't deal with LS but with Bochner-Stieltjes integral